How to test a model on user's input? (Predict Sentiment From Movie Reviews)
My code:
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

from keras.datasets import imdb
(training_data, training_targets), (testing_data, testing_targets) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

def OneHotEncoding_fn(IMDBData,dimension=10000):
   OneHotEncoded_Data=np.zeros((len(IMDBData),dimension))    
   for i, sequence in enumerate(IMDBData):
    OneHotEncoded_Data[i,sequence]=1.
   return OneHotEncoded_Data
    
training_data=OneHotEncoding_fn(training_data)
testing_data=OneHotEncoding_fn(testing_data)
training_targets=np.asarray(training_targets).astype('float32')
testing_targets=np.asarray(testing_targets).astype('float32')

model=models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation = "relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

data_validation=training_data[:5000]
training_data_without_val=training_data[5000:]
targets_validation=training_targets[:5000]
training_targets_without_val=training_targets[5000:]

model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(training_data_without_val,training_targets_without_val,epochs=25,batch_size=512,validation_data=(data_validation,targets_validation))

x = input('Write your review: ')
pred=model.predict(x)

I need to write my review (for exapmle "It was very interesting film") to test model's accuracy. After input, program have to encode my words to indexes relevant Keras IMDB indexes and output result (1 or 0). How to do this?
I tried to find info here: https://keras.io/api/datasets/imdb/ ,but it was unsuccessfully. I need to write a function that allows you to enter user's text (in the report, give an example of how the network works on user's text). Error:Unrecognized data type: x=It was very interesting film (of type <class 'str'>)

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.
